# How to register external procedure in Oracle on AWS RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle

I have Oracle database on AWS RDS (Oracle Standard Edition).

I need to register an external procedure written in C. According to [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntqrf/registering-an-external-procedure.html#GUID-7BC71588-E0C0-46EC-8C1A-AFB16C61269C), I need to set some environment variables in listener.ora file.

[image]

However according to [the AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/configuring-and-using-oracle-connection-manager-on-amazon-ec2-for-amazon-rds-for-oracle/), access to listener.ora is not possible.

[image]

Is there another method of registering external procedures without any need of modifying listener.ora file?

Comment: You can't use a managed service like RDS for that. No managed database (DBaaS) from any cloud provider will let you have that kind of access. You'd have to run your own VM (IaaS) and maintain the OS and database yourself to have that level of control.

Comment: Extprocs are security holes that have to be carefully locked down or they provide too much access. For example, if the listener intercepting the extproc IPC call is running (as it would be by default) under the "oracle" software owner, then any C code it runs would run with the permissions of the oracle software owner. It could delete database files, log in as SYS, do anything it wants. This isn't a model that most companies find acceptable. It *can* be tightened by running a listener under a non-privileged user, but that requires more setup and pieces that can be overlooked on a reboot.